# Adding pseudo selectors to Nativescript elements

Tags: javascript, css, sass, nativescript

How can I use button: hover in my nativescript Buttons?

I tried using

```
Button:highlighted{
  background-color: red;
}
Button:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
Button:touch{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The only pseudo selector currently available in {N} is `:highlighted` (https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#pseudo-selector) which can be used to style the pressed state of buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Taking your code something like this would do.

```css
 <style>
    button:highlighted{
      background-color: green;
    }
    button:hover{
      background-color: red;
    }
    button:touch{
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
    
    <button>Click Me!</button>
```

since you are associating CSS to button tag and applying styles on its pseudo state, thus button has to be made through button HTML tag its self not trough type call on input.

better option would be to make class then call it on anything your heart desires.

```css
<style>
    .btn:highlighted{
      background-color: green;
    }
    .btn:hover{
      background-color: red;
    }
    .btn:touch{
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
    <button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" class="btn">
```

Keeping as per what Turnip pointed out as to what OP was asking for, answer is updated. I am keeping the original answer intact because core fundamentals remains relevant.

Pseudo selector is the subject of CSS this all the dribble about classes remains relevant. CSS in interpreted in conjunction with HTML thus remains relevant. Native script variant of button
However it is the JS that is at play here aka native script.
Following are links for detailed walk through keeping in mind the original fundamentals.
[Styling](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling)

[Button Components](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/button)

[Overall UI Overview](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/overview)

[Gestures as suggested by @turnip](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures#touch)

Comment: The question is about Nativescript, not HTML. There are no `:hover` or `:touch` pseudo selectors in Nativescript.

Comment: @Turnip how do I think I can a press effect to any layout in my project?

Comment: @Syed There is the [gestures module](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures#touch) which you could use to detect touch events and then style through JavaScript.

Comment: @Turnip i have added your suggestion into the update as well.